# SVN migration lost lock property

Tags: svn, svnadmin

Due to lack of space and improvement of the server, I had to make a migration of the SVN server. When the operation was ended, all users could access to their projects without a problem.

But some users noticed that the files they had locked, they weren't, and other users could lock them instead.

The process I followed to make the migration was this.

Export from old SVN to dump file:

```
svnrdump dump http://svnserver/path/to/repository > /path/to/file.dump
```

Import dump file to new SVN Server:

```
svnadmin load --force-uuid /path/to/repository/ < /path/to/file.dump
```

I`ve repeated the import operation without --force-uuid parameter and I've got the same result.

Is there any way to keep the files locked doing a SVN migration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. I know the best practice to work with Subversion is with edit-merge method. I have always used it. But in this case, it is mandatory the use of files lock.

And other problem is that the new server environment has a different OS and a different version of Subversion, so I can't use hotcopy.

The solution that I found is copy the locks directory from old repository to the new one. The locks directory is placed in the db directory at the repository root (*/old_server/repository_name/db/locks*). I copy this to */new_server/repository_name/db/locks*. Both repositories have the same name. After do that, users get their old locks as nothing was happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
svnadmin dump
```

will not copy locks and hooks (as you have seen already), but you can use:

```
svnadmin hotcopy REPOS_PATH NEW_REPOS_PATH
```

A note from [link](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/665.cfm):

> Hotcopies created with svnadmin hotcopy must be moved to a server with
>   identical setup. You should have the same version of subversion
>   installed on both servers, same operating system, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ivan Jovovic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28219233/368630) mentioned, when you copy your repository, you don't get certain metadata that aren't really part of the repository itself such as locks.

However, in most Subversion shops, locks are rarely used. In fact, I can't think of the last time I've seen them used.

Older version control systems had a concept of a lock where you had to lock a file before editing it. This was like a library where you checked out a program, and only one person could do this checkout at a time. The problem was that this was very inefficient. If two developers wanted to change the same file, it meant that the second developer had to wait before doing their work. If that first developer took days to finish, that second developer had to wait days.

About a dozen years ago, a new concept of edit-merge took place. In this model, both developers could make changes, and the first one to commit their changes back into the version control system *won*. If the second developer wanted to check in their changes, they'd first have to update their working copy, get the changes that other developer did, and then check in their code.

All modern version control systems, Perforce, Subversion, Git, Mercurial, and others now use this edit-merge model. It's just a better way to work.

If you're still insisting on locking a file before it is changed, you should reexamine how you're doing development. There's a reason why version control systems have long abandoned the practice.

Comment: Not a useful response. OP specifically asked for how to keep locks, not advantage of not using locks. There are plenty of use cases where merging doesn't work because of proprieatary/binary file formats.